# VideoStream::setVideoMode() function doesn't work

Tags: c++, kinect, openni

I want to change VideoStream setting in my program, but it doesn't work

```
#include <OpenNI.h>

int main()
{
    OpenNI::initialize();
    Device device;
    device.open(ANY_DEVICE);
    VideoStream depthStream;
    depthStream.create(device, SENSOR_DEPTH);
    depthStream.start();

    VideoMode depthMode;
    depthMode.setFps(20);
    depthMode.setResolution(640, 480);
    depthMode.setPixelFormat(PIXEL_FORMAT_DEPTH_100_UM);
    depthStream.setVideoMode(depthMode);

    ...
}
```

Even I change `depthStream.start()` line after `setVideoMode()` function, but still doesn't work.

I changed Fps to 24, 20, 5, 1 but it doesn't change anything.

p.s. : This is my simple code, without error handling.

---

**Edit:**

**Answer:**
with the help of dear "api55" i found that my device (Kinect Xbox) support only one mode of videoMode. *so I can't change it.*

My only supported video is :

```
FPS:30
Width:640
Height:480
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I change the VideoMode succesfully in a [code](https://github.com/cvlabbonn/tools_openni2) a did before. After creating the VideoStream you should do something like:

```
rc = depth.create(device, openni::SENSOR_DEPTH);
if (rc != openni::STATUS_OK)
    error_manager(3);

// set the new resolution and fps
openni::VideoMode depth_videoMode  = depth.getVideoMode();
depth_videoMode.setResolution(frame_width,frame_height);
depth_videoMode.setFps(30);
depth.setVideoMode(depth_videoMode);

rc = depth.start();
if (rc != openni::STATUS_OK)
    error_manager(4);
```

First I get the VideoMode that is inside the stream to conserve the other values and only change what I wanted. I think your code should work, but not all settings work in all cameras. To check the possible settings you can use the function `openni::VideoStream::getSensorInfo`. The code to check this should be something like:

```
#include <OpenNI.h>

int main()
{
    OpenNI::initialize();
    Device device;
    device.open(ANY_DEVICE);
    VideoStream depthStream;
    depthStream.create(device, SENSOR_DEPTH);
    depthStream.start();

    SensorInfo& info = depthStream.getSensorInfo();
    Array& videoModes = info.getSupportedVideoModes();
    for (int i = 0; i < videoModes.getSize(); i++){
         std::cout << "VideoMode " << i << std::endl;
         std::cout << "FPS:" << videoModes[i].getFps() << std::endl;
         std::cout << "Width:" << videoModes[i].getResolutionX() << std::endl;
         std::cout << "Height:" << videoModes[i].getResolutionY() << std::endl;
    }

    ...
}
```

I haven't test this last piece of code, so it may have errors, but you get the idea of it. The supported settings change with each camera, but I think the supported FPS in my camera were 15 and 30.

I hope this helps you

Comment: my supported video modes is weird !!! only the first is normal :-? 
https://gist.github.com/mehdi1902/9e4d7308998d4ac82043

Comment: @mehD what camera are you using? I was using a primesense Carmine and got normal values always... maybe only one 640x480 at 30 fps is supported... the other ones don't make sense at all. This is my output https://github.com/cvlabbonn/tools_openni2/blob/master/possible_modes.txt

Comment: I'm using Kinect Xbox 360. 
So you have wide range of choices :)
but I'm not :(

Comment: Oh ok, I haven't try this with the kinect I have, but it's true that with openni it is a little more restricted, and also if it is linux or mac is not even supported at all, try anyways with 15 fps that is the other one that i saw it was supported in mine

Comment: Totally i want to change the resolution and fps to decrease the noise of depth frame. Can u help me about this issue ? tnx

Comment: googleing a little bit more, i found out that is not possible with the kinect.... you can only increase the resolution (and obtain lower fps)... A workaround would be to do the resize yourself (i.e. with opencv resize function) though i don't think the noise will be reduce much doing it like this... You may do some process to the image to reduece the noise. Or, if it is possible, get another camera with a wider selection of supported resolutions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57614/discussion-between-mehd-and-api55).